# Are objects returned from query using Hibernate HQL or Criteria pointers or the actual data from database

Tags: java, hibernate

So I know in java if you access a database using a connection and get query results in a resultSet the data is not actually returned its more of a pointer back to the data in the database.  My question is when using Hibernate is it the same thing.

I have my .java class posted below that relates to the table.

When I perform a query and lets say I used Criteria

```
List<TrackItem> list = null;
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(TrackItem.class);
c.add(Expression.between("itemTime, 100L, 200L));
list = c.list();
```

When I do list = c.list do I actually have the object or is it a pointer to the data in the database.

trackItem table's .java class

```
/**
* TrackItem generated by hbm2java
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "track_item", schema = "d2d")
public class TrackItem implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * ID.
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8469898950069782997L;
private long id;
private TrackItemType trackItemType;
private long itemTime;
private Long frameNumber;
private String imageSource;
private String trackItemUUID;
private Track track;

public TrackItem() {
}

public TrackItem(long id, TrackItemType trackItemType, long itemTime) {
    this.id = id;
    this.trackItemType = trackItemType;
    this.itemTime = itemTime;
}

public TrackItem(long id, TrackItemType trackItemType, long itemTime,
        Long frameNumber, String imageSource,
        String trackItemUUID, Track track) {
    this.id = id;
    this.trackItemType = trackItemType;
    this.itemTime = itemTime;
    this.frameNumber = frameNumber;
    this.imageSource = imageSource;
    this.trackItemUUID = trackItemUUID;
    this.track = track;
}

@Column(name = "frame_number")
public Long getFrameNumber() {
    return this.frameNumber;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Column(name = "image_source")
public String getImageSource() {
    return this.imageSource;
}

@Column(name = "item_time", nullable = false)
public long getItemTime() {
    return this.itemTime;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "track_id", nullable = false)
public Track getTrack() {
    return this.track;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "track_item_type_id", nullable = false)
public TrackItemType getTrackItemType() {
    return this.trackItemType;
}

@Column(name = "track_item_uuid", nullable = false)
public String getTrackItemUUID() {
    return this.trackItemUUID;
}

public void setFrameNumber(Long frameNumber) {
    this.frameNumber = frameNumber;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setImageSource(String imageSource) {
    this.imageSource = imageSource;
}

public void setItemTime(long itemTime) {
    this.itemTime = itemTime;
}

public void setTrack(Track track) {
    this.track = track;
}

public void setTrackItemType(TrackItemType trackItemType) {
    this.trackItemType = trackItemType;
}

public void setTrackItemUUID(String trackItemUUID) {
    this.trackItemUUID = trackItemUUID;
}
}
```

Comment: Um, I disagree with your very first statement. It would help if you would clarify exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have the actual object and child objects. Unless you have enabled lazy for child objects.

Comment: His question is not about how child objects get fetched.he is asking about data fetched from HQL or criteria is the pointer or actual data.

Comment: I answered that in my first sentence that it will be an actual object.